# Unable To Encode Special Charecters in Python Quote()

Tags: python, encoding, special-characters

I tried to encode the special characters using `quote()`.
It only encodes the spaces, and doesn't encode the special characters.

E.g.:

```
encodedata: f11d700a-42f2-4169-b24f-b1d3b2bfae16
encode=  urllib.parse.quote(encodedata)
```

It returns the same data:

output:  `f11d700a-42f2-4169-b24f-b1d3b2bfae16`

Any suggestions to encode special characters?

Comment: Hyphens aren't specal characters per the docs for `quote`.

Comment: @snakecharmerb  thanks for ur reply. but i would to like to convert those hypen into hex values to fetch the exact data in DB. if you have any idea please comment here.